# Push an object into an array

Tags: javascript, push

I'm trying to push an object into an array. This is my code

```
_.forEach(this.aRawListings, (aListing=> {
    if (this.isInLocation(aListing)) {
        aResults.push(aListing);
        console.log(aResults);
    }
 }));
```

and here is what I get:
[image: What I get]

I tried to replace push with concat but got the same thing. Could you please light me why? 
Thanks

Comment: can you post the input? also, it would be very good to know what's the expected output for that input.

Comment: what are we supposed to see? You pushed an object in an array, I see an object pushed in an array in your image?

Comment: What is the problem ? Everything looks fine to me : if you want to get the details of the object, just click on the arrow next to the index number

Comment: No, As you see, There are 4 objects, but When I click on the expand result, just see two results. This is my problem

Comment: can you post your _full_ code? where is `aResults` initialized?

Comment: My full code `let  aResults = [];
       _.forEach(this.aRawListings, (aListing=> {
        if (this.isInLocation(aListing)) {
         aResults.push(aListing);
        }
       }));`